# DESC in SQLite conditional ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to select records ordered by the following logic, however SQLite raises an error when DESC is in the conditional.

```
ORDER BY
CASE 
  WHEN parentGUID IS NULL THEN datePosted DESC
  ELSE datePosted
END
```

This is to achieve Facebook like ordering =- original posts (which always have null parentGUIDs) in order descending by date and replies to original posts ordered by date ascending.

Comment: you can't switch order by direction per row depending on the value of a column.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to sort different rows differently?

Comment: I updated my "answer". If you want to do what I describe, then I give up, seems quite hard to do in a single query :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right, you'll need to join to the table that has the date of the parent post.  If that's available, something like this should do:

```
DECLARE @X TABLE
(
ID  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
parentID INT,
datePosted DATE NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @X (parentID, datePosted) VALUES
    (NULL, '2010-01-01'),
    (NULL, '2010-01-02'),
    (1,    '2010-01-03'),
    (1,    '2010-01-04'),
    (1,    '2010-01-05'),
    (2,    '2010-01-06')

SELECT
    Post.parentID, Post.datePosted
FROM @X AS Post
    LEFT JOIN @X AS Parent ON Post.parentID = Parent.ID
ORDER BY
    -- Order by post date, or rather the parent's post date if one exists
    COALESCE(Parent.datePosted, Post.datePosted)
    -- Order by reply date
    Post.datePosted
```

This gives this output:

```
parentID datePosted
-------- ----------
NULL     2010-01-02
2        2010-01-06
NULL     2010-01-01
1        2010-01-03
1        2010-01-04
1        2010-01-05
```

Note that this will break if replies can have replies in turn; you'd need something more robust.  In MS SQL, I'd use a CTE, but I'm not very familiar with Sqlite.

Comment: Oh, thanks to Lukas for clarifying the OP's intent, hope you don't mind that I borrowed your sample data!

Comment: +1  FWIW, that `CASE ... END DESC` could also be expressed as `COALESCE(Parent.datePosted, Post.datePosted) DESC`

Answer (score 1):

With your correction, I think I now understand. Here's some sample data

```
|GUID|parentGUID|datePosted|
+----+----------+----------+
|1   |null      |2010-01-01|
|2   |null      |2010-01-02|
|3   |1         |2010-01-03|
|4   |1         |2010-01-04|
|5   |1         |2010-01-05|
|6   |2         |2010-01-06|
```

And I'm guessing you want this output:

```
|GUID|parentGUID|datePosted|
+----+----------+----------+
|1   |null      |2010-01-01|
|5   |1         |2010-01-05|
|4   |1         |2010-01-04|
|3   |1         |2010-01-03|
|2   |null      |2010-01-02|
|6   |2         |2010-01-06|
```

That's quite hard (and probably slow) to order in a single query