# how can i concatenate fields inside of my dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i have a dataset, `dataset1`:

i am trying to do:

```
select col1+col2, col3 from mytable
```

this does not work; however this is no problem:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from mytable
```

**how can i concatenate fields inside of my dataset?**

please note that `col1, col2, col3` are all VARCHARS. i've tried the `&` operator as well.

please see the image below. i get the `DEFINE QUERY PARAMETERS` dialogue when it doesnt like my query:

[image]

Comment: You want to have them in one row call dataset1 ? Is that correct ?

Comment: @Simon yes indeed that is correct. i want col1+col2 to be one field, not two fields

Comment: try SELECT concat(col1,col2) AS dataset1, col3 FROM mytable

Comment: @Simon you cant do that in sql server

Comment: `SELECT X + Y FROM Z` should work fine.  Can you expand on "does not work"?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades i agree with you that, that shoudl work. i've added a picture. as soon as i get rid of the concatenation, it works. selecting the fields individually works

Comment: @Simon please see the picture that i added

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double quotes are not appropriate string delimiters in MS SQL.  Try:

```
SELECT ppl.FirstName + ' ' + ppl.LastName AS ReferredBy
```

Putting your actual query in the question may help you get a faster response next time, since the concatenation is actually a red herring here.

Comment: Please note: you did not state your actual syntax in your original question (i.e. no mention of double quotes). If you had done that it would have saved everyone some time!

Comment: Two years on SE, 81 answers on SO, and overnight this is my most upvoted.  Something is wrong here.

Comment: i guess your attention to detail skills are even better than your programming skills!

Comment: @JonofAllTrades small things small minds. Nice of you to look at the picture ;)

Comment: Your other top answer was for a similar deed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836271/desc-in-sqlite-conditional-order-by/5836946#5836946 ... seeing through to the ops **true** problem. Sometimes another set of eyes do the trick.